# I can't receive a letter using UART

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, uart

I wrote a simple program where I transmit and receive a letter via UART. The transmit function works 100% but the receive interrupt function doesn't work at all... Can someone adjust the receive interrupt function so I can receive a string instead of a char?

```
#define FOSC 16000000 // Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1

void setup() {
  USART_Init(MYUBRR);
  interrupts();
}

void loop() {
}

void USART_Init(unsigned int ubrr) {
  /*Set baud rate */
  UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
  UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;
  UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);
  //Enable receiver and transmitter */
  UCSR0C = (1<<USBS0)|(3<<UCSZ00);
  /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
  UCSR0A |= (1 << RXCIE0);
  UCSR0C=0;
}
void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data) {
  /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
  while(!( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)));
  /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
  UDR0 = data;
}

ISR(USART__RXC_vect) {
  char ReceivedByte;
  ReceivedByte = UDR0;
  // Fetch the received byte value into the variable "ByteReceived"
}
```

Comment: How do you know you can't receive it since you aren't doing anything with it if you *do* receive it?

Comment: under ReceivedByte = UDR0;
i put USART_Transmit(ReceivedByte);
but still i didnt receive anything at the serial monitor

Comment: Does the serial monitor still work if you are intercepting the data via interrupts?

Comment: no it didnt work
i dont know whats wrong with my code
i using termite , but still i didnt receive anything
how can i receive a letter via uart by interrupt ? and how to receive a string via uart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ISR(USART__RXC_vect)
> {  
>   char ReceivedByte;
>   ReceivedByte = UDR0; 
> // Fetch the received byte value into the variable "ByteReceived"
> }
> ```

`USART__RXC_vect` is not the name of the interrupt vector, `USART_RX_vect` is.

If you don't get the name right there is no compiler warning, however the interrupt routine is not called.

---

> ```
> UCSR0A |= (1 << RXCIE0);
> ```

That line is wrong. `RXCIE0` is in `UCSR0B` not `UCSR0A`. If you set the bit in the correct register you will get an interrupt.

Comment: hey Nick .. i changed the name of the vector but still the interrupt function didnt work... ( i transmitted the received value )

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the exact code you are currently using?  One thing you could do it turn on an LED (eg. `digitalWrite (13, HIGH);`) inside the ISR to test whether or not the ISR is called. Perhaps the transmitting of the received value is not working.

Comment: See amended reply.

Comment: thx a lot nick the code is now working .. 
but whats the size of UDR0 because it can hold a whole string received via UART ,i thought it was 8 bits and can contain only a letter

Comment: UDR0 will hold one byte. I think the hardware has a double buffer (that is, it can receive the next byte while you are retrieving the most recently-received one).